# Late binding in jquery?

Tags: jquery

There is a table which has one row:

```
<table>
  <tr><td><span class="removeItem"></span></td></tr>
</table>
```

I use this to bind a function to a class:

```
  $('.removeItem').bind('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
  });
```

later, I add rows with the same class name (.removeItem) into the table:

```
var newRow = '<tr><td><span class="removeItem"></span></td></tr>';
$(table).append(newRow);
```

When I click on the first row item, it is removed. The dynamically added one is not.

Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use event delegation by placing a handler on the `table` with the [`delegate()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method:

```
$('table').delegate('.removeItem','click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    return false;
});
```

...you'll probably want to place an ID on the table in order to narrow your selection.

Now click events that bubble up to the `table` will invoke the handler if the item clicked matches the `".removeItem"` selector.

I also changed it to use the [`closest()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method  to get the nearest `<tr>` ancestor.

---

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/UxbcN/

This is generally preferred over `.live()` because it only needs to run the selector for clicks inside the `table` instead of all clicks in the entire `document`.

Comment: Thank you; this is a great answer - and a great use of exchange markdown.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function. This will bind the click event to future elements that match the selector.

```
$('.removeItem').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this is really helpful. I haven't seen that API call yet. The doc is very concise and even answered my questions about the downside of this call v.s. .bind().

Answer (score 0):

`bind()` by design only binds handlers to the results of `$("mySelector")` at that precise moment. You have two alternatives in your described scenario:

1. Call `bind()` on your new rows after you create them.
2. Call `live()` which binds against all current and future elements that match the selector. (See documentation for [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)).